# Is it safe to remove /var/cache to free space?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, disk-space

I am trying to free some disk space from my Ubuntu 12.04 installation before making an image of the partition. I was wondering if it is safe to delete the contents in `/var/cache`?

Here are the top list of `/var/cache` from `du`:

```
136M    ./oracle-jdk7-installer
105M    ./apt-xapian-index
82M ./apt
4.9M    ./debconf
3.4M    ./tomcat6
3.3M    ./man
2.9M    ./software-center
2.7M    ./postgresql
1004K   ./fontconfig
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Do not remove manually.
The proper way to do it is

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: That will only handle `/var/cache/apt` though.

Comment: Upvoted, David's comment. Still, in number of cases that might be enough (it was for me).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a tool like like [Bleachbit](http://bleachbit.com/more-info-download/) to safely clean up caches.

```
sudo apt-get install bleachbit
```

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link, as the answer can become invalid if the linked page changes or the target site is unreachable/permanently offline.